# Summing area of polygons within vector layer within zone using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, area, overlapping-features, summarizing

I have one vector layer with multiple polygons (purple). I also have a number of other vector layers which are catchment zones (I also have a layer where these catchments are merged).

Is there any way I can sum/calculate the areas of the purple polygons within each of the individual catchment zones?

I need this to work out a percentage of the area taken up by the purple polygons within each catchment.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS I can suggest using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume there are ten features in *'multiple_polygons'* (yellow), and three in *'catchment_zones'* (grey) accordingly, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following Query, it is possible to achieve the result

```sql
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.Name,
    c.geometry,
    ROUND(st_area(c.geometry), 2) AS "catch_area(m*m)",
    ROUND(SUM(st_area(m.geometry)), 2) AS "mult_area(m*m)",
    COUNT(m.geometry) AS "num_mult",
    ROUND(SUM(st_area(m.geometry))/st_area(c.geometry)*100, 2) AS "area_%"
FROM
    "catchment_zones" AS c
JOIN
    "multiple_polygons" AS m
        ON st_intersects(c.geometry, m.geometry)
GROUP BY
    c.id
```

The output Virtual Layer will maintain the original geometry and some initial attributes including several new, namely `"catch_area(mxm)"` (in square meters), `"mult_area(mxm)"` (in square meters), `"num_mult"` and `"area_%"`.

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

1. Intersect
2. Dissolve based on catchment ID
3. Create new field and calculate area

Answer (score 0):

Create a new attribute with [field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator). If your layers have the names `polygons1` (the catchment zones) and `poly2` (your small, purple polygons), then on `polygons1` use this expression: `array_sum(overlay_contains ('poly2', $area))`.

*Here, the organge layer is labeled with the expression from above, calculating the sum of the areas of all blue polygons contained inside each of the orange polygons:*
[image]